# Foiling two tensor products

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, exterior-algebra

I have this problem in exterior algebra where I have a function B and B is defined in the following ways.
$$
B\left( \left( \begin{array}{c} u \\ v \\ w \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{c} x\\y\\z \end{array} \right) \right) = uy-2uz-vx-3vz+2wx+3wz
$$

$$
B=b_{12}e^{12}+b_{13}e^{13}+b_{23}e^{23}=(b_1\otimes b_2)(e^1\otimes e^2)+(b_1\otimes b_3)(e^1\otimes e^3)+(b_2\otimes b_3)(e^2\otimes e^3)
$$
where $e^1 = (1,0,0)$, $e^2 = (0,1,0)$, and $e^3 = (0,0,1)$ and I am supposed to solve for $b_1$, $b_2$, and $b_3$. If the subscript versus superscript convention is confusing, let me add that my professor denotes vectors with subscripts and linear functionals with superscripts and I too am abiding by that convention. My big issue with this is how to foil the tensor products since I do not have much experience in this area?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the word "foil"? I haven't seen it used in this context before.

Comment: It's probably a misnomer but I mean it in the algebraic sense. As in what the product of those would look like.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you mean by it... You've seen the definition of a tensor product? And you seem to already be aware that $(b_1 \otimes b_2)(e^1 \otimes e^2) = e^1(b_1)e^2(b_2)$. I'm just not sure what it is you want to know!

Comment: Yes I have seen the definition of a tensor product, I know that $f\otimes g(a,b) = f(a)g(b)$ but the problem with this is that by doing this, it only accounts for three terms instead of the given six.  Does that tensor product in fact account for all six terms, and if so, how does it do so or how do I show that explicitly?

Comment: In other words how do I distribute these tensor products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to write $\varepsilon^i$ instead of $e^i$ to make the notation clearer: we have $\varepsilon^i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$. We want to write $B$ as some linear combination of the $\varepsilon^i \otimes \varepsilon^j$. Note that $(\varepsilon^i \otimes \varepsilon^j)(e_p \otimes e_q) = \delta_{ip} \delta_{jq}$ just as for the 1-dimensional case. This means if we write $$B = \sum b_{ij} \varepsilon^i \otimes \varepsilon^j$$ then $$B(e_i, e_j) = b_{ij}$$.

So we can write $B$ out explicitly with respect to the basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$: $$B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & -2 \\ -1 & 0 & -3 \\ 2 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$ which is exactly the matrix $b_{ij}$ that you're looking for.

However, this does mean you won't get an expression of the form $B = a \varepsilon^1 \otimes \varepsilon^2 + b \varepsilon^2 \otimes \varepsilon^3 + c\varepsilon^1 \otimes \varepsilon^3$, so it's possible that I have misunderstood exactly what it is you're asking for!

Comment: As it happens, you indirectly answered my question so thank you very much!!